# Почему VideoCapture в opencv перестает извлекать изображение из буфера, хотя видео еще не закончилось?

Tags: python, opencv, компьютерное-зрение, opencv-faq

Есть видеофайл, записанный с камеры gopro 9. Когда я открываю его через cv2.VideoCapture, изображения захватываются на протяжении первой секунды, после чего cv2.read() возвращает False, хотя само видео идет 20 секунд. Я думаю, что дело именно в gopro, поскольку любой другой видеофайл, который записывался не с gopro, считывается нормально. Видео на gopro записывал с разными кодеками (hevc/h.265, avc/h.264), с разным разрешением и частотой кадров, все равно после первой секунды видеопоток прерывается. Попробовал переконвертировать видео используя софт handBrake, все заработало. Почему я не могу захватить все кадры с видео записанным с gopro 9?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.